# Asus X99 Deluxe fails to boot (overclocked)

Tags: motherboard, overclocking

I have made a clean reinstall of windows 10 and updated my BIOS and unfortunately my overclocking settings are now gone. I always had my CPU overclocked. But now i can't boot to windows if overclocked. I get stuck always at the spinning dots when windows should take over the control and the spinning dots just freeze.

[image]

My motherboard code at that point is always AA.

[image]

And later i need to force shutdown and in bios says Overclocking failed.

Can anyone give some good advice...i think i just need to enable or disable something so that it works as before.

Specifications:

CPU: Intel core i7 5820K
MBO: Asus X99 Deluxe
RAM: 4x8GB Kingston HyperX 2666 MHz
GPU: GTX 970

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after a few days I have finally came to a conclusion and a solution.
The only problem is the RAM memory and it needs to be "trained" before turning on the PC if it's overclocked and fast boot needs to be disabled.

My PC now works in Adaptive mode. That means that if I'm idling (reading something, surfing the internet or doing stuff that don't need the CPU power) my CPU frequency will be at 1200 MHz and if I start doing something that needs the CPU power it will jump to 3300 MHz and if it needs even more power,  it will jump all the way up to 4500 MHz.

So i will post the settings in photos here in hope it will help someone:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]